# Issue with window.replace() method having search params in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, replace, browser, window

I m trying to open a new window from my web page while clicking on the 'number#' lsted in my page, actually, it's a google search(eg: https://www.google.com/search?q=12312), and got the results in the new tab

I am also trying to replace the search query parameter again while clicking on another Number#(eg: https://www.google.com/search?q=456456), But replace functionality not working.
Below I am placed the demo code

```
let win;
let firstSearch = () => {
    win = window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=123123', '_blank');
}

let secondSearch = () => {
    win.location.replace('https://www.google.com/search?q=345345')
}
```

But its not working. But I remove '/search' from the URL replacement is happen.
So, any solution for this search and replacement parameters

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/varunsree/pen/PoEMYBV)

Answer (score 0):

That is not working because the site tells the browser that they don't want to be loaded in X-Frame. That's why your code works using Bing but not Google...

**from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options**

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.